# No exact matches in call to initializer in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I want to learn Combine framework for Swift and I have found a tutorial video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbY1KTI0g70

Unfortunately, I get:

```
No exact matches in call to initializer
```

error on the line which defines tableView and some other errors when I try to call the tableView, but I hope they will resolve after I fix the issue with initialising this element.

The code:

```
import UIKit
import Combine

class MyCustomTableCell: UITableViewCell{ }

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    private let tableView = UITableView {
        let table = UITableView()
        table.register(MyCustomTableCell.self,
                       forceCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        return table
    }()
```

(...)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.frame = view.bounds
```

(...)

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return models.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? MyCustomTableCell else {
            fatalError()
        }
        cellTextLabel?.text = models(indexPath.row)
        return cell
    }
```

The whole code is long as hell. That is why I copied only the crucial parts of it (where the tableView occurs).
You can see the full code in the video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbY1KTI0g70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's either

```
 private let tableView = UITableView( ... )
```

or

```
 private let tableView : UITableView = { ... }()
```

Comment: Thanks very much, @vadian. This syntax was new and strange to me.

Comment: Does the second kind of syntax have a name, @vadian? I would like to learn some more about it if possible.

Comment: It's called [Setting a Default Property Value with a Closure or Function](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID232)